# Combine two numbers into one. Example: 123 and 456 become 123456

Tags: c++, parsing, formatting

In C++, how do I combine (note: not add) two integers into one big integer?

For example:

```
int1 = 123;
int2 = 456;
```

Is there a function to take the two numbers and turn intCombined into 123456?

**EDIT:**

My bad for not explaining clearly. If int2 is 0, then the answer should be 123, not 1230.  In actuality though, int1 (the number on the left side) would only have a value if int2 goes over the 32 bit limit.  So when int2 is 0, then int1 is 0 (or garbage, i'm not sure).

Comment: If `int2` is 0, is the answer `123` or `1230`?

Comment: Is `int2` always 3 digits? If so, `(int1*1000)+int2` works. This could probably be modified for any `int2`, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: Interesting problem. Not sure what the best approach is. Hmmm

Comment: @ R Samuel Klatchoko: the answer should be 1230.
@ igul222: each int will be a 32 bit number that could range from 0 to 2^32, and the combined number will be a 64 bit number if there is an overflow.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The power of ten, that you need to multiply the first number with, is the smallest one, that is bigger than the second number:

```
int combine(int a, int b) {
   int times = 1;
   while (times <= b)
      times *= 10;
   return a*times + b;
}
```

Comment: except times starts at 10, to handle the case when b = 0, see the question comments.  AFAICT that fix makes this approach the only non-string method that yields the correct answer.  Plus multiplication is faster than division, this replaces a bunch of divisions with a single multiply.

Comment: I like this answer the best so far, but it would be better if you used log10 instead of the loop.  Also, you might want to make the return type a 64-bit int.

Comment: @sth All you need to do is change the while to a do-while, and b=0 is accounted for. Best Answer!

Comment: @csj I think this solves my question.  I mistook the b=0 scenario (read my edit in question).  Thank you all :)

Comment: @rmeador what whould be the exact code if we replaced the loop with log10 ?

Answer (score 9):

You could convert them into strings, combine them and then convert them back to an int?

Comment: you certainly can but this must be one of the slowest ways possible

Comment: but the most understandable, every developer can read and understand it in less than a second

Comment: In addition combining 2 numbers have its flaws, such as integer overflow etc. so this is a good way to combine them

Answer (score 9):

If the numbers you are trying to combine are positive integers you can use [pairing Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).

Pairing function creates a unique number from two. It is also a reversible function.

```
x,y -> z
z -> x,y

z = (x+y)(x+y+1)/2 + y
```

Then the reverse is:

```
w = floor((sqrt(8z+1)-1)/2)
t = (w*w + w)/2
y = z - t
x = w - y
```

Note. The above is not in any specific language. Just some math...

Answer (score 7):

For each digit in `int2`, you can multiple `int1` by 10 and then add `int2`:

```
// merge(123, 0) => 1230
int merge(int int1, int int2)
{
    int int2_copy = int2;
    do
    {
        int1 *= 10;
        int2_copy /= 10;
    } while (int2_copy);

    return int1 + int2;
}
```

You could get rid of the loop using `log10` and `ceil`.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't trying to copy you. You just beat me to the punch.

Comment: Return type should be something 64 bit (__int64 for MSVC, long long for gcc, might also depend on platform). Also int1 as used in the loop should be 64 bit. Ah, and "int" is not necessarily 32 bit either, so again platform specific type needed :).

Comment: This function looks clock cycle hungry.  Would the method posted below by Buckley work better?  If so, can anyone show the code?  If not, why is the merge() way better\more efficient?

Comment: @Bei337 I think converting to string actually requires a loop of divisions by 10 to extract the characters. I would bet money that this is less cpu intensive than Buckley's suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming both ints are non-negative, and int1 goes on the left and int2 goes on the right, you need to figure out how many digits long int2 is, multiply int1 by 10 a bunch of times, and then add them.

```
unsigned int int1 = blah;
unsigned int int2 = blah;

unsigned int temp = int2;

do
{
    temp /= 10;
    int1 *= 10;
} while (temp >0)

unsigned int newInt = int1 + int2;
```

Comment: Great approach CSJ. Did you copy from the guy above (Samuel).

Comment: @Germ I wasn't trying to copy - Samual was faster at getting it up.

Comment: @Germ: This is the common solution, I suspect many people were writing it. I was writing the same thing as Samuel (though I was using log10 and ceil), but stopped when I saw he posted it. csj just happened to be a bit faster than me.

Comment: CSJ - I didn't know you two were so intimate

Comment: GMan - I was just giving him a hard time

Comment: @Ben Good Call. It should be fixed now.

Comment: @csj Can we use the formula: result = (firstNumber * 10) + secondNumber ?

Answer (score 4):

You could use stringstream:

```
string Append(int _1, int _2){
    stringstream converter;

    converter << _1 << _2;

    return converter.str();
}
```

then call `atoi` on the returned string.

Comment: Could you explain a little on stringstream?  I'm not familiar with this.

Answer (score 2):

The following is essentially sth's accepted solution but with the b==0 fix, and the loop replaced with an expression to calculate the scale directly:

```
#include <math.h>

int combine(int a, int b) 
{
    int times = 1;
    if( b != 0 )
    {
        times = (int)pow(10.0, (double)((int)log10((double)b)) + 1.0);
    }
    return a * times + b ;
}
```

In some circumstances (such as a target with an FPU and a good maths library) the expression might be faster than the loop, but I have not tested that hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that works for C too:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int CombineInt(int int1, int int2)
{
  char cResult[32];

  sprintf(cResult, "%d%d", int1, int2);
  return atoi(cResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long int size, j;
    cin >> size;
    string s1, s3;
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        cin >> s3;
        s1 = s1 + s3;
    }
    int a=stoi(s1);
    cout<<a<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is using [strcat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcat-wcscat-mbscat?view=msvc-170):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(void)
{
   char string[80];
   int a=123,b=456;
   strcat(string, std::to_string(a).c_str());
   strcat(string, std::to_string(b).c_str());
   printf("%s\n",string);
}
```

But there are a problem: If `b`=0, then the result of `string` is 1230.

To fix this problem, this is the code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main( void )
{
   char string[80];
   int a=123456,b=0;
   strcat(string, std::to_string(a).c_str());
   if (b!=0) strcat( string, std::to_string(b).c_str());
   printf("%s\n",string);
}
```

You did say "intCombined", then, we need a integer. This is the code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main( void )
{
   char *string=new char[50];
   int a=123456,b=0;
   strcat(string, std::to_string(a).c_str());
   strcat( string, std::to_string(b).c_str());
   printf("%i\n",atoi(string));
}
```

But, as I said, it was output as 1234560, this is the code to fix it:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main( void )
{
   char *string=new char[50];
   int a=123456,b=0;
   strcat(string, std::to_string(a).c_str());
   if (b!=0) strcat( string, std::to_string(b).c_str());
   printf("%i\n",atoi(string));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{ 
int num1,num2,comb,a,c;

    cout << "Enter the 1st numbers" << endl;
    cin>>num1;
    cout << "Enter the 2st numbers" << endl;
    cin>>num2;
    a=num2/10;
    if(a<=9){
        c=num1*100;
    comb=c+num2;
    cout<<"The combination of the two numbers is "<<comb;
    }
    else if(a>9&&a<=19){
        c=num1*1000;
    comb=c+num2;
    cout<<"The combination of the two numbers is "<<comb<<endl;
    }
     else if(a>19&&a<=29){
        c=num1*10000;
    comb=c+num2;
    cout<<"The combination of the two numbers is "<<comb<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yous should explain your idea. Code without explanations has little value. Please add explanations to your post.